# DataBinding: Choose one of string resources depends on condition

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a boolean variable in my data-object, and want to show 1 string from resources when it is true, and another when it is false.
I am trying to do it this way:

```
android:text="@{sendit.bccMode ? @string/sharebox.bcc_mode_on : @string/sharebox.bcc_mode_off}"
```

But getting an compilation error:

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor java.lang.String.bcc_mode_on

What do I am doing wrong?

Comment: put your string.xml file here

Comment: <string name="sharebox.bcc_mode_on">BCC mode on</string>
<string name="sharebox.bcc_mode_off">BCC mode off</string>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Databinding` library is lost when you use the . (dot) as a name, change your `strings.xml` file to this:

```
  <string name="sharebox_bcc_mode_on">BCC mode on</string>
  <string name="sharebox_bcc_mode_off">BCC mode off</string>
```

Answer (score 7):

To be exact, you don't have to rename your strings with an underscore in place of a dot, just replace dots by underscores when you USE this string :

**in the file strings.xml :**

```
<string name="sharebox.bcc.mode.on">BCC mode on</string>
<string name="sharebox.bcc.mode.off">BCC mode off</string>
```

**in the databinding (in activity.xml)  :**

```
android:text="@{sendit.bccMode ? @string/sharebox_bcc_mode_on : @string/sharebox_bcc_mode_off}"
```

So you just have to convert '.' to '_' when you use this strings in databinding